# Auto delete post if certain custom field data is empty

Tags: functions, custom-field

This question can be stupid but I really need a solution for it..
I am generating classified post using cron job. I have some custom filed as well with the cron job like 'source_link'. Sometimes that custom filed data may not be set for error or any kind of situation.
So I want that post with empty data for custom field 'source_link' to be deleted automatically.
Is this possible anyway ?

Here the code how I do I create post and set custom field data

```
            kses_remove_filters();
            $new_id = wp_insert_post($post_arr, true);

            kses_init_filters();

            if (is_wp_error($new_id)) {
                $this->write_log("error occurred in wordpress post entry: " . $new_id->get_error_message() . " " . $new_id->get_error_code(), true);
                return;
            }
            update_post_meta($new_id, 'source_link', $url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    kses_remove_filters();
    $new_id = wp_insert_post($post_arr, true);

    kses_init_filters();

    if (is_wp_error($new_id)) {
        $this->write_log("error occurred in wordpress post entry: " . $new_id->get_error_message() . " " . $new_id->get_error_code(), true);
        return;
    }

    if($url)   update_post_meta($new_id, 'source_link', $url);
    else {
        // wp_delete_post($new_id); // Move post to trash
        $deleted = wp_delete_post($new_id, true); // Permanently delete post
        if(! $deleted ){
             $this->write_log("error deleting post entry.", true);
             return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Simple solution but I couldn't imagine!